# PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: text = boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

There is a JSONB `information` field with this structure:

```
{
  "ignore"=>false
}
```

I want to get all records whose `ignore` field is `true`:

```rb
@user.posts.where("information ->> 'ignore' = TRUE")
```

This line throws an error:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = boolean
```

And I could not find anything in Google. Everywhere we are talking about textual meanings. But there is nothing about booleans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must cast the result of `information->>'ignore'` to boolean:

```
@user.posts.where("(information ->> 'ignore')::boolean = TRUE")
```

Comment: I tried both options - it doesn't work. The result is not filtered - both `true` and `false` are present.

Comment: Can you add the logs to your question? And also the structure of the posts table (`\d+ posts` in psql).

Comment: Your third option is doing something terrible. I get several times more data than there is in the database. Well, it does not filter anything.

Comment: I don't have idea how your tabe looks like, nor about the records there. I asked you for a simple describe of your table, without that is difficult to know what's your problem.

Comment: There is a `jsonb` `information` field in the table that contains what I showed in the text of the question. A simple table with simple fields.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in upgrading to Rails 5/6. It seems the way the `pg` gem casts has changed a little, but this works for me:

```
@user.posts.where("(information ->> 'ignore')::boolean = ?", true)
```

When an argument is added as the second parameter to a `where` method call, ActiveRecord will do the work to cast this appropriately for you. If you add `.explain` to the query above, you should see something like:

```
EXPLAIN for: SELECT ... AND ((information ->> 'ignore')::boolean = TRUE) ...
```